# Adding padding to the beginning and end of a UIStackView

Tags: ios, uistackview

I've been switching over to `UIStackView` recently and trying to do all my layout with it and it's so much easier than using Auto Layout... with one exception.

I have a layout using nested `UIStackViews` with a vertical stack view and inside it is a horizontal stack view.

Like this...

```
|    Label    |
|    Label    |
|Button Button|
|    Label    |
```

This is fine except I now want to have a space between the buttons and the edges of the screen. I can set a space between the buttons but not at the edges.

Is there a way to do this?

What I would like is this...

```
|   B     B   |
```

The buttons both have a background colour with rounded corners. I'd like a gap between the edge of the screen and the background.

If that makes sense.

I just can't find anything that would allow me to do this.

Comment: how about setting insets on the buttons

Comment: @Wain that moves the contents but doesn't change the background. I have updated my post to explain about the background. Thanks

Comment: @Wain well, it seems that "spacer views" aren't going anywhere for now. The only way I got it to do what I wanted was to add zero width views to each end of the stack view. LOL

Comment: How about adding  a padding of few pixels on left and right of vertical stackView?

Comment: @Muneeba exactly... that's what I'm asking. How do you do that? Have you tried?

Comment: yes i tried it.. Take  a vertical stack view and put your controls as u mentioned above and add left and right constraint on vertical stack view with constant of 10 and inside your vertical stack view add horizontal stack view and put those two buttons in that . Output is this http://imgur.com/RE8mvX1

Comment: @Muneeba ah, I see what you mean now. But there is content in the vertical stack that needs to go to the edge of the screen. It's just the buttons that don't.

Comment: Then you should break your vertical stack into further more . or take out the buttons  stack view out of vertical stackview.

Comment: @Muneeba I'll try breaking it up a bit. Taking the button stack view out of the vertical one would mean they are no longer stacked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100462/discussion-between-muneeba-and-fogmeister).

Comment: I see you went to chat. Was there an answer? @Fogmeister

Comment: @finneycanhelp yes! You can use the `layoutMargins` on the stock view to add padding to the inside of it.

Answer (score 13):

StackView doesn't have padding attribute as of iOS 14 / Xcode 12. But we could set the layout margin.

- through Interface Builder:

[image]

---

### OR

- through code, could configure the stack view to lay out its arranged subviews relative to its layout margins:

`stackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true`

> For iOS > 10

`stackView.directionalLayoutMargins = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 16, leading: 16, bottom: 16, trailing: 16)`

> For iOS <= 10

`stackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 16, left: 16, bottom: 16, right: 16)`

---

P.S drawback of this approach, when the StackView has no subviews, it would persist its layout margins. Therefore to remove the paddings we should set a layout margin with zero edge insets through code.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a super old question, but you can do it like this:

- **add 0px wide UIViews to both sides of the horizontal stack view**
- set their background color to `clearColor`
- set the horizontal stack view's `Distribution` to `Equal Spacing`.

[**Update**: I just saw you mentioned this in the comments]